# Swift Encoding: possible to have variable keys?

Tags: swift, encoding

Say I have a struct:

```
struct Animal {
  var age: Int
  var type: String
}
```

I know I can define my custom coding keys but what I want is, when I encode a struct into a JSON, instead of:

```
{
  "age": 12
  "type": "dog"
}
```

I want it be:

```
{
  "12": "dog"
}
```

But I'm not sure if this is possible with the built-in encoding mechanism?

Comment: If you insist on using that format (where the key in your JSON isn't a key, but another value), you would be better off using `JSONSerialization` and navigating the dictionary yourself. But I'd seriously discourage you from using that sort of structure. What if you later add another property, e.g. `weight`. How are you going to distinguish one from another? What are you going to do if the 12 lb dog is 12 years old? It seems like you're trying to violate basic JSON guidelines for the sake of a few bytes...

Comment: @Rob Yes true, this is not good, but I guess if extra fields are added, they will follow the basical rule of key value pair, just for this instance, I am required to export data in this special format.

Comment: “I am required to export data in this special format” ... Lol. Yeah, sometimes we’re saddled with poor designs. Still, I’d suggest you escalate this to the attention to the project manager, because it’s a really poor design. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the `Encodable` protocol to do this, you're going to need to define a custom key type that will allow you to represent the value variably, and write `encode(to:)` yourself:

```
struct Animal : Encodable {
    var age: Int
    var type: String

    private struct CodingKeys : CodingKey {
        var stringValue: String
        var intValue: Int?

        init?(stringValue: String) {
           self.stringValue = stringValue
           self.intValue = nil
        }

        init?(intValue: Int) {
           self.stringValue = "\(intValue)"
           self.intValue = intValue
        }
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(type, forKey: CodingKeys(intValue: age)!)
    }
}
```

I have to reiterate what @Rob said, which is that this is a terrible idea, but if this is the format you're required to encode to, it's still possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can Custom function for Json:

```
struct Animal {
    var age: Int
    var type: String

    var jsonString: String {
        return "{\"\(age)\": \"\(type)\"}"
    }

    var jsonObjc: Any? {
        if let data = jsonString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
            return try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers)
        }
        return nil
    }

}


let animal = Animal(age: 1, type: "dog")
print(animal.jsonString)
print(animal.jsonObjc ?? "nil")
```

print content:

```
{"1": "dog"}

{
    1 = dog;
}
```

hope help for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is there a way to do this via the builtin Encoding mechanism?

Comment: @hzxu Sorry, I not found.